Does SharePoint store everything of a OneNote notebook in SQL?
Suppose I have a 20GB OneNote notebook hosted on SharePoint. Will all of this data be stored in the SQL database or is the SQL database only used for meta data?
Background of my question is that I am thinking of using the Express Edition of SQL server with SharePoint 2013 Foundation, which has a 10GB database limit.

SQL Server Express Edition is not supported for SharePoint. Furthermore, yes, SharePoint content is stored in content databases.

SQL Server Express is not supported. Azure SQL Database (the non-Managed Instance DBaaS service) is also not supported for any SharePoint databases.


A Standard or Enterprise Edition of SQL Server for Windows that supports database compatibility level 130.

Source: Minimum requirements for a database server in a farm

Thanks, i should mention I am using SharePoint 2013 (Foundation) which even comes with the Express version. I’ll update question. But just to make sure, also for 2013, the maximum size of all files in SharePoint (incl OneNote notebooks) could not exceed 10GB?

There is no limit size for SharePoint. Only your SQL Server edition or hardware can limit your usage.

This answers my question then. So with SharePoint 2013 Foundation + SQL Server Express, all stored files combined (incl OneNote notebooks) are limited to total 10GB size.

That version of SharePoint is no longer supported.
